# Vim inside tmux on Mac OS X Mavericks can't copy to clipboard

Tags: macos, vim, tmux, clipboard

Since going to Mavericks, I've lost the ability to use the clipboard in vim when run under tmux.

I install vim via brew. For reference, yes, the +clipboard option is definitely set.

When I run vim inside a terminal directly, I can access the system clipboard normally via `*` and `+`. But when running vim inside tmux, no such luck. I also have clipboard support turned on in tmux, so perhaps this is part of the problem.

For reference:

- vim 7.4.52
- tmux 1.8

In my .tmux.conf:

```
set -g set-clipboard on
```

Nothing is set in my .vimrc to explicitly turn on support. However, I'll note that adding the usually recommended option (which I've never needed before):

```
set clipboard=unnamed
```

has no effect.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Are you running into the problem that https://github.com/ChrisJohnsen/tmux-MacOSX-pasteboard solves?

Comment: Yep, that was the problem. Somehow, despite being installed, `set-option -g default-command "reattach-to-user-namespace -l zsh"` had gone missing from my .tmux.conf.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem, although with macOS Sierra, VIM 8.0, tmux 2.3. My fix comes by way of user joshuamcginnis at https://github.com/tmux/tmux/issues/543. Make sure you have `reattach-to-user-namespace`:

```
$ brew install reattach-to-user-namespace
```

Then in `.tmux.conf`:

```
set -g default-shell $SHELL 
set -g default-command "tmux rename-window zsh; reattach-to-user-namespace -l ${SHELL}"
```

The `rename-window` part is optional. Otherwise new windows are named `reattach-to-user-namespace`.